# Proper use of IDisposable with Managed Members

Tags: c#, resources, garbage-collection, unmanaged, idisposable

If a **member-of-a-member** implements IDisposable, should IDisposable then be implemented all the way up the chain?

For example, in the following case the DbClass opens an SqlConnection (which implements IDisposable). So should **both** DbClass and BusinessLogic implement IDisposable?

Is this basically C#'s version of RAII/destructors then?

Do I need to (or shoud I in the case of best practice) implement a finalizer?

I'm having some difficulty figuring out the proper way of doing this, so thanks in advance.

```
class Program
{
    private BusinessLogic bl;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BusinessLogic bl = new BusinessLogic();
    }
}

class BusinessLogic
{
    public DbClass _db;

    public BusinessLogic()
    {
        _db = new DbClass();
    }
}

class DbClass
{
    private SqlConnection _conn;

    public DbClass()
    {
        _conn = new SqlConnection("connection string");
        _conn.Open();
    }
}
```

Comment: In .NET, you typically create a new connection to a database every time you need one. That way, the connections are cleaned up in the method that created them and you don't have to worry about implementing `IDisposable` on all your classes.

Comment: Thanks JRLambert. My app performs many DB operations as a batch (user presses "GO", app communicates very heavily with the DB for the next 2 minutes). The interactions are all within transactions, I believe that should help to prevent memory exploding. I was thinking to keep the DB connection open for the duration of the batch, then "destroy" everything. I'm not sure whether or not that is a suitable way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's define any type, which implements `IDisposable`, as a *managed resource*.

### About finalizers.

Since you don't have *unmanaged* resources (file or socket handles, pointers etc), you don't need to implement finalizer, because finalizers are intended for unmanaged resources cleanup.

Actually, after [`SafeHandle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) was presented in .NET 2.0, there are very rare cases, when one should work with really unmanaged resources (everything wrapped into `SafeHandle` are managed resources already).

The explanation below assumes, that you're dealing with managed resources only.

### About `IDisposable` implementation.

If some type *owns* managed resource, then it must dispose it as well.
If managed resource is created per operation, then it must be disposed after operation is completed:

```
class A
{
    void Method1()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(/* ... */))
        {
            // load data from database
        } // the resource (connection) will be disposed here
    }
}
```

Note, that you don't need `A` to implement `IDisposable`.

If managed resource should live as long, as its owner, then owner must implement `IDisposable` and must dispose managed resource in its `Dispose`:

```
sealed class B : IDisposable
{
    private readonly SqlConnection _conn;
    private bool _isDisposed;

    public B()
    {
        _conn = new SqlConnection(/* ... */);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
            return;

        if (_conn != null)
            _conn.Dispose();

        _isDisposed = true;
    }
}
```

Hence, if instance of `class C` owns `B` instance in the same manner, it also must implement `IDisposable`, and so on. Here's a little difference between `Dispose` implementation in `sealed` and non-`sealed` types: for non-sealed types you should implement `Dispose` like this:

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_isDisposed)
            return;

        // dispose managed resources of base type
        // ...
        OnDispose();

        _isDisposed = true;
    }

    protected virtual void OnDispose()
    {
    }
```

If some type *does not own* managed resource, then it must not dispose it:

```
class D // do not implement IDisposable, since we don't own connection
{
    private readonly SqlConnection _conn;

    public D(SqlConnection conn)
    {
        // connection is created elsewhere, and will be used by another objects
        _conn = conn;
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        //  read data from database using connnection...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Dennis. Final question regarding your example with class "A". If we remove the "using" statement, the garbage collection will still clean up the connection, no? Since the connection will have no references outside the scope of the method. So do we need to clean it up at all in the case of "A"?

Comment: Yes, you do need to cleanup it. Don't confuse determined resource cleanup with memory cleanup. When you're calling `Dispose`, you're cleaning up resource here and now (close a file, socket, connection, etc.). The object still remains in memory - you just can't "free" it, but GC can. On the other hand, GC doesn't cleanup managed resources. The only thing it does, is a call to finalizer. This will cleanup *unmanaged* resources, **but**:

Comment: 1) you can't predict, when this will happen; 2) you must not put cleanup code for managed resources into finalizer, since managed resources in finalizer could be in unpredictable state (e.g., they could be collected by GC already).

Answer (score 0):

First consider whether your DbClass should hold an SqlConnection member.  An alternative would be for each method of DbClass that needs a connection to have a local SqlConnection inside a using statement.  When the method exits (cleanly or by exception) the SqlConnection from using state will get disposed.
This means
a. You are never holding open connections for extended periods when you dont need them.
b. There is no longer any need for any of your classes to implement IDisposable.
It is my (limited) undertanding that this is the recommended way of using connections and that it scales better.

Answer (score 0):

To understand `Dispose`, one must understand what it means for an object to own a resource; the concept is actually very simple, but Microsoft never really defines it.

An object *acquires a resource* when it asks an entity *outside itself* to maintain until further notice a state which is beneficial to the object, but potentially detrimental to other entities.  An object *releases a resource* when it notifies the aforementioned outside entity that *its services are no longer required*.

If code creates a `File` object, the constructor of that object will ask an outside entity (the OS file manager) for exclusive use of a file.  This will benefit the `File` object, but be detrimental to anything else that might want to use the file.  Calling `Dispose` on the `File` object will cause it to notify the OS file manager that it no longer needs that file, and the file manager may thus make it available to other entities.

If some other class `FooFormatter` creates a `File` object and stores it in a field, the act of creating the `File` will say to the file class "Please acquire exclusive access to the a file with this name and make it available to me [the calling code] until further notice".  At that point, the `FooFormatter` will have asked the `File` to establish state which is beneficial to the `FooFormatter` but bad for everything else.  Such action would represent acquiring a resource, and in taking such action the `FooFormatter` would have accepted an obligation to notify the `File` when it is no longer needed.  When the `File` receives such notification, in will in turn notify the OS file manager.

Note that some (though not all) .NET objects which acquire a resource will ask the Runtime to notify them if they seem to be abandoned, and will attempt to release resources if so notified.  This is a process called "Finalization"; resources encapsulated by such objects are called "managed resources"; resources of any type which will not be cleaned up automatically if their owners are abandoned are "unmanaged resources".  Note that implementing `IDisposable` does not imply that something is a managed resource, since many objects do not (and in some cases cannot) implement finalizers that clean up their resources.  Not also that finalization should almost never be relied, upon, since there is no guarantee of timeliness or success; in most cases, one would be better off pretending that no such mechanism existed, and regard code which abandons resource-holding objects as broken.

The $50,000 question with regard to whether objects which have `IDisposable` fields should implement `Dispose` and call `Dispose` on those fields is whether the objects identified by those fields are maintained in a non-disposed state *for the benefit of the object holding the fields*.  If the answer is yes, then the object holding the `IDisposable` objects should implement `Dispose` so it calls `Dispose` on the nested objects.  If the answer is no--the fields identify objects owned by some other object--then the fields should not be disposed.